# Корректно ли данное высказывание?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, значение-слов

Внимание!
Прибор не предназначен для использования лицами
(включая детей) с пониженными физическими, чувственными или умственными способностями или при отсутствии у них опыта или знаний, если они не находятся под контролем или не проинструктированы об использовании прибора лицом, ответственным за безопасность. Дети должны находиться под контролем для недопущения игры с прибором.

Интересует вся фраза, но больше всего слово "чувственными"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимание! Прибор не предназначен для использования лицами (включая детей) 
с **ограниченными** физическими, **чувственно-сенситивными** или умственными способностями или при отсутствии у них опыта или знаний, если они не находятся под контролем или не проинструктированы об использовании прибора лицом, ответственным за безопасность.

Пояснение: чувственно-сенситивная способность - это  способность человека получать информацию об объектах с помощью органов чувств.Чувственное познание разделяется на чувственно-эмоциональное и чувственно-сенситивное.

Comment: Vera, спасибо за комментарий

Comment: А вас, Вера, "пониженные умственные способности" не шокируют?

Comment: В моем варианте "ограниченные умственные способности", так можно сказать?

Comment: Нет, конечно. В школе это называется "этическая ошибка", если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: А по-моему это термин, например: http://www.consultant.ru/law/ref/ju_dict/word/rebenok_s_ogranichennymi_umstvennymi_ili_fizicheskimi_vozmozhnostyami/

Comment: В наименовании термина именно "возможности", это более дипломатично: когда в таком контексте кому-то отказывают в "способностях", обычно намекают на его безнадёжность, зачастую с намерением унизить.

Comment: Термин термином, его и следует употреблять там, где следует. А не в магазине.

Answer (score 1):

> > Интересует вся фраза, но больше всего слово "чувственными"

А меня "умственными". Это что, будет некая официальная бумага? Вы когда-нибудь встречали подобные?

Comment: Розничная сеть требует написать это на информационном стикере ко всем электро товарам, причем слово в слово. А мне кажется, что это мало того, что некорректно (это про умственные), но и не правильно. Поэтому решила уточнить.

Comment: <<Прибор не предназначен для использования лицами <…> если они <…> не проинструктированы об использовании прибора лицом, ответственным за безопасность.>> 
Аналогично:
Книги не предназначены для неграмотных.
Расчёски не предназначены для лысых.
Очки не предназначены для слепых. 
Это нормально?..
Настаивайте на перестройке всей фразы.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь каскад отрицаний и конъюнкций с дизъюнкциями - надо упрощать текст даже для лиц с достаточным опытом и знаниями в области родного языка.

Прибор предназначен для использования лицами с достаточным опытом и знаниями, в противном случае обязательно инструктирование пользователя лицом, ответственным за безопасность. Использование прибора лицами с ограниченными физическими возможностями [перечисление таковых], а также детьми допускается только под контролем ответственных лиц.